# Scale flex box height to fit image div

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox

I am building a chat message and I want to fit an image inside the text bubble. The bubble has a fixed width and should scale its height depending on the image aspect ratio.

I am unable to scale the div to maintain the `img` aspect ratio. All of the answers found use an `<img>` tag, while I am using a div and none of that fixed my issue.

This is the desired outcome:

[image]

[image]

What I have achieved instead is either a very small `img` (size of an empty speech bubble if I do not impose any vertical or horizontal dimension) or a long `img` if I impose the width and keep the height dynamic.

```css
.speech-right-wrapper {
  max-width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

speech-right-message-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.speech-right-bubble {
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(154, 226, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px gray;
  border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  display: flex;
}

.bubble-background {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bubble-background-img {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="speech-right-wrapper">
  <div class="speech-right-message-container">
    ...
    <div class="speech-right-bubble">
      <div class="bubble-background">
        <div class="bubble-background-img" v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + require('../assets/img/profiles/' + storyPath + bubble.bubble_background) + ')' }" v-bind:alt="bubble.bubble_background"></div>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

For clarity, I need the `<div class="bubble-background-img">` to be fix in width (say 200px) and `height: auto` to maintain the image aspect ratio; and I need the `<div class="speech-right-bubble">` to scale to fit the image inside.

Also, unfortunately I need to use a `<div>` tag because `v-bind:src` seems not to work for local images. If I do:

```
<img class="bubble-background-img" v-bind:src="'../assets/img/profiles/' + storyPath + bubble.bubble_background"/>
```

I get this: [image]

Comment: will be much easier if you can create a fork for your app using [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Can't you use an `<img>` tag or is it that the solutions you looked at that said to use an `<img>` tag didn't work?

Comment: @Dadboz, I can't share the full code.

Comment: @Victor, the app is in Vue and I can't render an image with an img tag. After many attempts, I found that 'v-bind:style' with 'require' works with no problems.

Comment: doesn't `v-bind:src` not work with your url variable?

Comment: The web is filled with issues on binding `src` for local images. Some get an error, I get the icon when the img is not found or the link is broken. I just tried again for the sake of it, but I just can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably find a workaround for your `v-bind:src` issue since the correct way to display a content image is via the HTML `img` element.

That said, there is a solution, but it relies on using the CSS `content` property for element replacement, which is a fairly recent technology that's apparently still not supported in Microsoft Edge. The following CSS code is the gist of it and worked for me in testing in Firefox 68:

```
div { content: ('image.jpeg'); max-width: 200px; }
```

(In theory, a variation of this technique should also work with the more backward-compatible CSS `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, but the image inexplicably doesn't scale in my testing. I didn't spend much time experimenting though.)

Comment: Neat solution, and support isn't as patchy for element replacement as I expected!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a hundred percent certain what you are going for, but you could try setting the background-size as a percentage?

```
background-size: 100%;
background-position: center center;
```

Using a percentage in background size lets you scale one or more axis according to the parent container. (e.g. `background-size: 100% 100%;` would scale width and height, and give an effect equivalent to the `contain` value).

Would that work?

(Personally, I would load the image using an  element as that's what they are there for, and you could use `object-fit` as appropriate, but obviously depends on how you've architected the view...)

Comment: Alan, my explanation is probably not clear: I need the picture to be 200px wide and `height: auto` to maintain its own aspect ratio. I need the parent div `class="speech-right-bubble"` to scale its dimension so to fit the image inside.